# nth-child(odd) for an ordered list rows in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to apply the `nth-child(odd)` to ordered list rows but it doesn't cover all the row width... any suggestion?

```css
li{
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 20px; 
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

li:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: violet;
}
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add "display: block;" property to the li element.

```
li {
  font-family: serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px; 
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list-style-position: inside;`  means that the bullet points will be inside the list item. As it is part of the list item, it will be part of the text and push the text at the start

Also there is default `padding` of `ul` tag which can be removed by commented code

```css
/*ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}*/

li {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  list-style-position: inside;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>Text 3</li>
  <li>Text 4</li>
  <li>Text 5</li>
</ul>
```